# FuelUX programmatically change wizard steps

Tags: fuelux

Is there a way to programmatically switch between fuelux wizard steps using jquery?

Something like:

```
var $wizard = $('#MyWizard').wizard();

$wizard.next()
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very close!  Please try this:

```
$('#MyWizard').wizard('next');
```